# Create Grid in another page (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an 'AddNote' page and a 'HomePage' page. I want to create a grid on the 'HomePage' page when the 'TakeNoteBtn' button is clicked in the 'AddNote' page. How can i?

```xml
XAML button code in AddNote page;
<Button
                CornerRadius="30"
                Text="Take Note"
                x:Name="TakeNoteBtn"
                Margin="20, 30, 20, 0"
                Clicked="TakeNoteBtn_Clicked"
                BackgroundColor="FloralWhite"/>
```

```cs
AddNote page c#;
       private void TakeNoteBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            //Create grid
        }
        public Grid CreateGrid(string header, string note)
        {
            Label headerLabel = new Label();
            Label noteLabel = new Label();
            headerLabel.Text = header;
            noteLabel.Text = note;
            Grid noteGrid = new Grid();
            noteGrid.Children.Add(headerLabel);
            noteGrid.Children.Add(noteLabel);
            noteGrid.WidthRequest = 50;
            noteGrid.HeightRequest = 50;
            noteGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            return noteGrid;
        }
```

```xml
HomePage page xaml;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
             x:Class="ArduinoNotes.HomePage"
             BackgroundImageSource="background.png"
             IconImageSource="logo.png"
             Title="Arduino Notes">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RelativeLayout x:Name="HomePageGridZone">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: Solution Explorer]

I tried ArduinoNotes.HomePage.HomePageGridZone.Add(CreateGrid(noteHeader, noteBody)); but not worked.

Comment: Use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to pass a message to from one page to another.  This is much cleaner than having one page directly modify the UI of another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `MessageCenter` to achieve this.

If you want to achieve this with `MessageCenter`. you can refer to the following code:

1. add A button( `Take Note with messagecenter`) on page `AddNotePage.xaml`

   ```
        <Button 
            Text="Take Note with messagecenter"
            x:Name="TakeNoteBtn2"
            Margin="20, 30, 20, 0"
            Clicked="TakeNoteBtn_Clicked_withMessageCenter"
           />
   ```

and function `TakeNoteBtn_Clicked_withMessageCenter` on `AddNotePage.xaml.cs`

```
    private void TakeNoteBtn_Clicked_withMessageCenter(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //Create grid
        //method 2
        string[] values = { mHeaderEntry.Text, mNoteEntry.Text };

        MessagingCenter.Send<AddNotePage, string[]>(this, "Note", values);

        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

2.on `HomePage`, Subscribe message on the constructor method `HomePage`, and after the page receives message, you can add grid on this page

public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
public HomePage()
{
InitializeComponent();

```
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AddNotePage, string[]>(this,
    "Note", async (sender, values) =>
    {
        string header = values[0];
        string content = values[1];

        Grid grid = CreateGrid(header, content);
        HomePageGridZone.Children.Add(grid);

    });

    }
// other code
}
```

Besides, you can also use `EventHandler` to achieve this.

And I have achieved this function, you can refer to the following code:

Suppose that the `HomePage` is the main page,and we can click a Button on `HomePage` to navigate to `AddNotePage`. Once clicking one button (`add note`) on `AddNotePage`,we can pass two parameters( `note Header` and `note content`) to the `HomePage`.Here,we can create a Grid by using the two passed parameters `note Header` and `note content` on `HomePage`.

**HomePage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="EventHandlerApp.HomePage"
              Title="HomePage"
             >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="HomePageGridZone">

         <Button  Text="navigate to add note page" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
      
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**HomePage.xaml.cs**

```
   public partial class HomePage : ContentPage 
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AddNotePage, string[]>(this,
    "Note", async (sender, values) =>
    {
        string header = values[0];
        string content = values[1];

        Grid grid = CreateGrid(header, content);
        HomePageGridZone.Children.Add(grid);

    });
        }

        void BackCall(object send, NoteModel obj)
        {

           DisplayAlert("Alert", "add a new grid", "OK");

            // here we can get the passed parameter s
            if (send != null && obj!=null)
            {
                Grid grid = CreateGrid(obj.Header, obj.NoteContent);
                HomePageGridZone.Children.Add(grid);
            }
        }

        public Grid CreateGrid(string header, string note)
        {
            Label headerLabel = new Label();
            Label noteLabel = new Label();
            headerLabel.Text = header;
            noteLabel.Text = note;

            //Grid noteGrid = new Grid();
            Grid noteGrid = new Grid
            {
                RowSpacing = 0,
                ColumnSpacing = 0,
                RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition(),
                new RowDefinition(),
            },
              ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition(),
            }
            };


            noteGrid.Children.Add(headerLabel,0,0);
            noteGrid.Children.Add(noteLabel,0,1);
            noteGrid.WidthRequest = 50;
            noteGrid.HeightRequest = 50;
            noteGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            return noteGrid;
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddNotePage page = new AddNotePage();
            page.mEventHandler += delegate (object s, NoteModel a)
            {
                BackCall(s, a);
            };

            Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        }
    }
```

**AddNotePage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="EventHandlerApp.AddNotePage"
             Title="AddNotePage"
             >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="add a new note"
                VerticalOptions="Start" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <StackLayout   Orientation="Vertical" >

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text=" header: " WidthRequest="60" ></Label>
                    <Entry x:Name="mHeaderEntry"  Placeholder="header"  WidthRequest="200"  />
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="note: " WidthRequest="60" ></Label>
                    <Entry x:Name="mNoteEntry"  Placeholder="note" WidthRequest="200" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

            <Button
                CornerRadius="30"
                Text="Take Note"
                x:Name="TakeNoteBtn"
                Margin="20, 30, 20, 0"
                Clicked="TakeNoteBtn_Clicked"
               />

           <Button 
            Text="Take Note with messagecenter"
            x:Name="TakeNoteBtn2"
            Margin="20, 30, 20, 0"
            Clicked="TakeNoteBtn_Clicked_withMessageCenter"
           />

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**AddNotePage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AddNotePage : ContentPage 
{

    public  EventHandler<NoteModel> mEventHandler; // define a EventHandler

    public AddNotePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TakeNoteBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create grid

        EventHandler<NoteModel> handler = mEventHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            NoteModel model = new NoteModel();
            model.Header = mHeaderEntry.Text;
            model.NoteContent=mNoteEntry.Text;

            mEventHandler(this, model);

            Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }

    private void TakeNoteBtn_Clicked_withMessageCenter(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //Create grid
        //method 2
        string[] values = { mHeaderEntry.Text, mNoteEntry.Text };

        MessagingCenter.Send<AddNotePage, string[]>(this, "Note", values);

        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }

}
```

**NoteModel.cs**

```
public class NoteModel 
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string NoteContent { get; set; }
}
```